# trailing zeros calculation in jquery with points values

Tags: jquery, trailing

Hi I'm trying to calculate values with standard way like `12,000.00` or `1,678,900.00` or `0.36` values but its not calculating my values if comma or point exists. here is my code [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6654544h/15/)

for example

I'm giving the values

Payment Sent 1: `12,000.00`

Payment Sent 2: `1,678,900.00`

Payment Sent 3: `0.36`

Now Total Payment Sent convert into `0.00` values

Total Payment Sent: `0.00`

So how to calculate these values properly.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao [**that**](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6654544h/16/) doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function paymentSentSum() {
      var totalPaymentSent = 0;
      var that;
      $(".paymentSentSum").each(function() {
         that = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/\,/g,''));
         if(!isNaN(that) && that != 0) {
            totalPaymentSent += that;
         }
      });
      $("#paymentSentTotalPaymentSent").val((totalPaymentSent).formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
    }

    function addTrailingZerosBookings() {
      var that;
      $(".paymentSentSum").each(function() {
        that = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/\,/g,''));
        if(that && !isNaN(that)) {
            //$("#" + $(this).attr('id')).val(trailingZeros(this.value));
            if(isAlphaNumeric(that)) {
                $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).val(that.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
            } else {
                $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).val(this.value);
            }
         }
      });
    }
```

Here use this. I have used parseFloat initially when to get the amount and then applied your checks. Rest all is good.

Code Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqLgB

Comment: I guess you mistook. Read it again.

Comment: Check out the code pen [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqLgB](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqLgB) it works as expected

Comment: Man!!! I know it works, so take a +1. You still didn't understand my question or answer my question! LoL.

Comment: there is only one problem if I enter value `12000` it convert it into `12,000.00` like this but if I enter value `12,000` with comma it is not adding trailing zeros.

Comment: and what if I enter double comma it should be convert into single comma with trailing zeros.

Comment: `Mr. joyBlanks` need a little help more.

Comment: @user3833682 tell me. was this the intent ? I am getting confused

Comment: it is working fine but the problem is with `Number.prototype.formatMoney = function` now if I enter value `12000` its convert into `12,000.00` trailing zeros with comma, what if I enter value `12,000` with comma it is not converting my value into trailing zero so how to handle this one.

Comment: This is going to be the same replace , and etc. Give me some time I will get back

Comment: Please look at the updated Pen [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvByza](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvByza)

Comment: `User. joyBlanks` can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205232/trailing-zeros-with-comma-functionality-using-php